# Redirect STDOUT by variable in Bash

Tags: bash, stdout, io-redirection

I want to create a script which can be run both in verbose and silent mode if preferred. My idea was to create a variable which contains `"&> /dev/null"` and if the script is runned silently I just clear it. The silent mode works fine but if I want to pass this as the last "argument" to something (see my example down) it does not work.

Here is an example:
I want to `zip` something (I know there is a `-q` option, the question is more like theorethical) and if I write this it works as I intended:

```
$ zip bar.zip foo
  adding: foo (stored 0%)
$ zip bar.zip foo &> /dev/null
$
```

But when I declare the `&> /dev/null` as a variable I get this:

```
$ var="&> /dev/null"
$ zip bar.zip foo "$var"
zip warning: name not matched: &> /dev/null
updating: foo (stored 0%)
```

I saw other solutions to redirect parts of the script by intention but I'm curious if my idea can work and if not, why not?
It would be more convenient to use something like this in my script because I only need to redirect some lines or commands but too much to surround each with an `if`:

I'm trying something like this to be clear:

```
if verbose
verbose="&> /dev/null"
else
verbose=

command1 $1 $2
command2 $1
command3 $1 $2 $3 "$verbose"
command4
```

Comment: use eval: `eval zip bar.zip foo "$var"`.

Comment: or use if statement: `if condition; then command; else command >& /dev/null; fi`

Comment: As mentioned above and below, I don't want to surround everything with `if`s and `eval` is discouraged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bash` will recognize a file name of `/dev/stdout` as standard output, when used with a redirection, whether or not your file system has such an entry.

```
# If an argument is given your script, use that value
# Otherwise, use /dev/stdout
out=${1:-/dev/stdout}

zip bar.zip foo > "$out"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the order of expansion performed by the shell.  The variable is replaced by your stdout redirect AFTER passing the commands to the command `zip`

You need the shell to expand that variable BEFORE invoking `zip` command. TO do this you can use `eval` which takes a first pass at expanding variables and such.

`eval zip bar.zip foo "$var"`

*However* be weary of using eval, as unchecked values can lead to exploits, and its use is generally discouraged.

You could consider setting up your own *file descriptor* and set that to be /dev/null, a real file, or even stdout.  ANd then each command that should go to one of those would be:

`zip bar.zip foo > 3`

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#FDREF

Comment: Please try to avoid linking the ABS -- it's the W3Schools of bash, full of bad-practice examples and outdated information, yet with an inexplicable amount of Google juice.  The bash-hackers' wiki has two great pages on redirection -- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection -- and there's also solid coverage in the BashGuide (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput) and, of course, the official manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).